# Silverlight: Error deserializing XML

Tags: xml, silverlight, deserialization

I'm building a Silverlight 4 app. I'm trying to use XElement to read XML. The following code doesn't work for me:

```
        string data = @"<?xml version='1.0'>
                        <Data>
                          <TopicGroups>
                            <TopicGroup>
                              <Name>Documents</Name>
                              <Id>0</Id>
                            </TopicGroup>
                          </TopicGroups>
                          <Topics>
                            <Topic>
                              <Name>Foo stuff</Name>
                              <Id>1</Id>
                              <GroupId>0</GroupId>
                            </Topic>
                          </Topics>
                          <PlumFiles>
                            <PlumFile>
                              <Name>moons</Name>
                              <Body>we're going to the moon</Body>
                              <TypeExtension>docx</TypeExtension>
                              <Author>Frodo</Author>
                              <CreatedOn>2010-11-18T00:00:00-05:00</CreatedOn>
                            </PlumFile>
                          </PlumFiles>
                        </Data>";

        // crash here
        XElement xml = new XElement(data);
```

The exception is:

```
System.Xml.XmlException: Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C.

   at System.Xml.XmlConvert.VerifyNCName(String name, ExceptionType exceptionType)
   at System.Xml.XmlConvert.VerifyNCName(String name)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XName..ctor(XNamespace ns, String localName)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XNamespace.GetName(String localName, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XNamespace.GetName(String localName)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XName.Get(String expandedName)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XName.op_Implicit(String expandedName)
   at PlumPudding.MainPage.MainPage_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)} System.Exception {System.Xml.XmlException}
```

What could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:-

```
XElement xml = XElement.Parse(data);
```

The XElement constructor is expecting an `XName` to define simple the name of the element to construct (or a string that will be implictly converted to an `XName`).